# Silverlight WebClient.DownloadStringAsync() only work out of browser

Tags: silverlight, get, webclient, silverlight-5.0

My Silverlight 5 app uses WebClient to upload and download json content. POST requests are working fine, however GET request are working only in out-of-browser context.

Here is my server's clientaccesspolicy.xml

```
<access-policy>
    <cross-domain-access>
        <policy>
            <allow-from http-request-headers="*" http-methods="*">
                <domain uri="*"/>
            </allow-from>
            <grant-to>
                <resource include-subpaths="true" path="/"/>
            </grant-to>
        </policy>
    </cross-domain-access>
</access-policy>
```

Does anyone know how to make GET requests work in on-browser context?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by 'not working'? Do you get exceptions?

Comment: Also, do you set some special headers with your requests?